# How to specify key and value comparers for checking dictionaries in Fluent Assertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'm just getting started with Fluent Assertions 4.1.1. Looks like the code for comparing dictionaries is

```
 actualDictionary.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(expectedDictionary);
```

but how do I specify my own equality function (comparer) for the keys and values if I don't want to use their Equals() implementation?

For collections it seems to be:

```
actualCollection.Should().Equal(expectedCollection, MyComparisonFunc);
```

I'm looking for the `IDictionary<K,V>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>` equivalents of that.

**Edit**: same question for Contain() on a collection.

Answer (score 1):

There's are overloads of `Should().Contain()` and `Should().Equal()` for collections that take a predicate, but unfortunately, none exists for dictionaries. However, the equivalency rules are highly extendible. Checkout the [unit tests](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/blob/e240c8c8d02160fd69e22d7590901df429f86bd3/Tests/FluentAssertions.Shared.Specs/ExtensibilityRelatedEquivalencySpecs.cs) to see some examples